Catalog_Search Index
What does Catalog_Search index index? It takes over 40min to do and I need to extend the memory to 4gb to make it work. I thought it was because we had 62k products, but I just removed almost 40k products. And still takes forever and exceed the memory when doing it the normal way.
So what can make this take so long?
This did not take so long before we upgraded to Magento 2.4.6 and PHP 8.1. When we used Magento 2.4.3 it only took 2min.
Magento 2.4.6
